# How to make JavaFX 2 wrapper discover an existing installation on Linux systems?

Tags: java, linux, cross-platform, javafx-2

Dealing with [JavaFX 2-generated JNLPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413136/how-to-make-jnlp-download-the-correct-version-of-javafx-2), I discovered that JavaFX comes with an Ant task that creates a JAR with an integrated launcher.

On Windows systems, the launcher automatically discovers an existing JavaFX installation on the `PATH` and uses it to satisfy the application's dependencies.

I couldn't get the same wrapped JAR to run on a linux systems.
JavaFX's most current linux build is installed, and I have placed its `lib` directory on my `PATH`, yet all I see is an (AWT-based) message window telling me to install JavaFX.

Since I learned about the (as-yet-)lack of JNLP support for linux yesterday, my question is twofold:
Can the wrapper pick up installations on linux, or is this feature not implemented yet?
What preconditions do I have to meet so it discovers my installation?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801463/building-javafx-2-0-app-on-mac-deploying-on-windows) dealing with a related issue on Mac OS.

Comment: I know your question is 3 months old, but I was just curious if you have tried the [2.2 Developers Preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)? From my understanding that when 2.2 is out essentially the it should be cross-platform.

Comment: Not yet. We have built our own solution by now, and are waiting for 2.2 GA to try again.